# Android - Including library project from another library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an android application and two Android library projects. The application project requires 1st library project and has it on its Android dependencies. The 1st Android library project requires the 2nd Android library project and has it on its own Android dependencies. The problem is that the 1st Android library project does not see resources from 2nd Android library project and the are comiplation errors. How to configure the projects?

Comment: Everything works fine for me with the same setup. Make sure all of your library projects have your sdk.dir setup in a local.properties file. This is generated automatically by running 

"android update project -p ."

from within your project directory (use command line to run that).
You may be able to do the same thing from within eclipse by right clicking on the project and going to "Android Tools"->"Fix project properties"

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you can figure out the root cause of the error.

Comment: What revision of the SDK tools are you using?

Comment: The problem now I have is: [2012-12-08 15:53:37 - TURInfo.Legi] [AndroidManifest.xml:1, AndroidManifest.xml:23] /manifest/supports-screens defined in library, missing from main manifest:
<supports-screens>
    android:smallScreens = true
    android:normalScreens = true
    android:largeScreens = true
    android:anyDensity = true